# reactjs components are all displaying

Tags: reactjs, react-router

After having logged on I just want the Administrate component to come up, but my Login component is still displaying as well.

boot-client.tsx :

```
import * as RoutesModule from './routes';

    function renderApp() {
        ReactDOM.render(

            <AppContainer>
                <Provider store={store}>
                    <ConnectedRouter history={history} children={routes} />
                </Provider>
            </AppContainer>
            ,
            document.getElementById('react-app')
        );
    }
```

routes.tsx:

```
export const routes = <div>   
<PrivateRoute  component={FetchData} />
<Route path='/' component={Logon} />
<Route path='/administrate' component={Administrate } />  
  </div>
 ;
```

my component 'PrivateRoute' is as follows and needs to redirect to the administrate component after having logged in:

```
export const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={props => (
        localStorage.getItem('user')
            ? <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/administrate', state: { from: props.location } }}/>
            : <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location } }} />
    )} />
)
```

Can somebody point me in the right direction? What am I overlooking? Thanks a million.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `exact` to your `/` route else both `/` and `/administrate` will match.

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Route.md#exact-bool

Answer (score 3):

thats because the url matches to both paths. 
Additionally I would surround it with a `<Switch>` which forces it to only display one of them. This is nice for adding a default path as-well, otherwise the default path will always gets displayd